# Solve for reals: $a(b+c-a^3)=b(c+a-b^3)=c(a+b-c^3)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for reals:

$a(b+c-a^3)=b(c+a-b^3)=c(a+b-c^3)=1$

I found cyclic relation

$c=(a+b)(a^2+b^2)$

and a solution $a=b=c=1$

But now I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial solution:
Let $S=a+b+c$, then $a^4+a^2+1=aS$.  This quartic has three solutions $a$,$b$,$c$.   Suppose they are all different.
The sum of the quartic's four solutions is 0, so the fourth solution is $-S$.  So $S^4+S^2+1=-S^2$, and $(S^2+1)^2=0$.
This can't happen in reals, so we must have at least two equal: $a=b$

Now $a^4-a^2+1=ac$, $c=a^3-a+1/a$, and $((a^4-a^2+1)/a)(2a-(a^4-a^2+1)^3/a^3)=1$
WolframAlpha says that either $a=1$,$a=-1$ or $$a^{12}-2a^{10}+5a^8-4a^6+4a^4-2a^2+1=0$$
But the polynomial $=a^8(a^2-1)^2+a^4(2a^2-1)^2+(a^2-1)^2+2a^4$ which is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is $(a,b,c)=(-1,-1,-1)$ and your triple these are the only real solutions.
eliminating the variables $b,c$ we get for $a$
$$ \left( {a}^{12}+2\,{a}^{10}+7\,{a}^{8}+8\,{a}^{6}+7\,{a}^{4}
-2\,{a}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( a-1 \right)  \left( a+1 \right)  \left( 
{a}^{12}-2\,{a}^{10}+5\,{a}^{8}-4\,{a}^{6}+4\,{a}^{4}-2\,{a}^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( {a}^{6}+{a}^{4}+2\,{a}^{2}+1 \right)=0
$$
with the solutions above.